How can I justify using counts plus offset in a Poisson or NB model instead of "percent of total"?
I have count data that is part of a whole. It's not compositional, because the other parts of the whole aren't of interest. I could analyze it as a "percent", but I would rather do it as counts plus offset (log whole). How do I explain the benefits of using the offset rather than the percent to hidebound PIs?

This probably hinges on "the other parts of the whole not being of interest" -- a percentage is a proportion from which the number of observations was discarded. Does that matter, i.e. do all observations have a similar sampling basis (denominator)? Even so, if the denominator is relevant and it is a count as well a binomial GLM might be an approach to consider?

You might be interested in Goodness of fit and which model to choose linear regression or Poisson

Perhaps it makes sense to split questions. Why model data as counts? You are less likely to draw inferences about impossible values (percentages between counts). Count=0 is naturally within distribution (might not be if you try to use something like LogNormal).
Why model counts as offset + target? Could be variance. For example Poisson distribution implies variance equal to mean, and negative binomial only allows to have greater variance, not smaller. You can try to find or construct a distribution with sub-Poissonian variance, but why do it if there is a reality-based way to avoid it? If you did model your problem as continuous data you could still face this small-variance issue, but it may be more of a numerical nuisance.
